# regular expression - value not equal to

Tags: php, regex

Can you advise on a regular expression for:

NOT EQUAL TO string1, string2, string3 and case insensitive

I have the following, but not giving me what I want.

```
/^(?!string1|string2|string3)$/
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry if I'm on the wrong path, but why not negate the positive match?

```
if (!preg_match("/^(string1|string2|string3)$/i",$str) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Sometimes it's too obvious :)

Comment: Thanks - figured it out from what you provided. Needed pure regex'/^(?!string1|string2|string3).*$/i'

Comment: /^(?!string1|string2|string3$)/ if you'd like to match against the complete string: e.g 'string1' matches, but 'string12' doesn't.

Comment: @BasTaller actually it doesn't have to match 'string12', these were only placeholders for the actual strings, but yes in your way that would be the correct expression :)

Answer (score 1):

You would need an `AND` in regex, not `OR`. Because if your string was `string3`, it will be unequal to `string1` and `string2`, so it would match. <s>You cannot solve this with regular expressions (at least not in a way that would be readable I assume ;)).</s> *Of course you can by inverting the output of the match.*

You could also use a non-regex approach (might be easier to maintain):

```
$blacklist = array('string1', 'string2', 'string3');

if(!in_array(strtolower($str), $blacklist)) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?
    if( !preg_match( '/(string1|string2|string3)/i', $str ) )

Answer (score 0):

I use this when I need to find "a file that does not contain..." :

(?s)\A((?!Copyright).)*\Z

This is for the string "Copyright"... replace the string as needed; as well as the \A (beginning of a file) and \Z (end of a file).